# WPF: How to pass Content property between styles and ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

I'm trying to switch between two styles in WPF according to a property.
To switch between the styles I used ControlTemplate for each style and one style with triggers that switching between the ControlTemplates.
My problem is that I have a ContentPresenter inside each basic style and I cannot set it from outside (from the usages).

This is my code in xaml:

```
    <Style x:Key="SecondaryButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF494F5A"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24.5" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="76" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,0,10,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource ButtonEffect}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                    <Grid>                        
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>                        
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonMouseOverBackground}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonIsPressedBackground}" />
                    </Trigger>


                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="SecondaryButtonWithArrowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonNormalBackground}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF494F5A"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24.5" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="76" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource ButtonEffect}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5,32,32,5"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,4,0,4">
                            <Path Data="F1M46,23.478C46,10.512 35.704,0 23,0 10.299,0 0,10.512 0,23.478 0,36.44 10.299,46.951 23,46.951 35.704,46.951 46,36.44 46,23.478" 
                                    Fill="#FF646A74" x:Name="Path"/>
                            <Path Data="F1M12.504,9.03L9.823,9.028 5.15,9.025 12.273,1.903 10.369,0 1.903,8.466 0,10.369 10.369,20.739 12.273,18.836 5.144,11.706 9.822,11.709 12.502,11.711 20.912,11.715 20.913,9.035z" 
                                    Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>                        
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonMouseOverBackground}" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonIsPressedBackground}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="NormalButton">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource SecondaryButtonStyle}"  />
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrowButton">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource SecondaryButtonWithArrowStyle}" />
</ControlTemplate>


<Style x:Key="SwitchButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NormalButton}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ArrowButton}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The usage is:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SwitchButtonStyle}" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

How can I make the button to take the `Content="Back"`?

Thank You!

Anna.

Comment: So since you have the separate styles anyway, and I assume your condition is a bool at some point, why not just swap out separate buttons with visibility and a converter instead of all this swapping of styles on the same object? Performance wise it would make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but we thought about it and got to a conclusion about the future what will happen if we will need 5 different styles with an enum property and not a bool - a trigger make it more easy to use and no converter is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this:
I changed the styles to ControlTemplate and created a basic style that will be the BasedOn style of the main style with the triggers.

The new code is:

```
<Style x:Key="BaseButtonWithArrowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonNormalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF494F5A"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24.5" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="76" />
            <Setter Property="Effect" Value="{StaticResource ButtonEffect}"/>
        </Style>


        <ControlTemplate x:Key="NormalButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                        <Path Data="F1M46,23.478C46,10.512 35.704,0 23,0 10.299,0 0,10.512 0,23.478 0,36.44 10.299,46.951 23,46.951 35.704,46.951 46,36.44 46,23.478" 
                                    Fill="#FF646A74" x:Name="Path"/>
                        <Path Data="F1M12.504,9.03L9.823,9.028 5.15,9.025 12.273,1.903 10.369,0 1.903,8.466 0,10.369 10.369,20.739 12.273,18.836 5.144,11.706 9.822,11.709 12.502,11.711 20.912,11.715 20.913,9.035z" 
                                    Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonMouseOverBackground}" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonIsPressedBackground}" />
                </Trigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>


        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ArrowButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="5,32,32,5"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,4,0,4">
                        <Path Data="F1M46,23.478C46,10.512 35.704,0 23,0 10.299,0 0,10.512 0,23.478 0,36.44 10.299,46.951 23,46.951 35.704,46.951 46,36.44 46,23.478" 
                                    Fill="#FF646A74" x:Name="Path"/>
                        <Path Data="F1M12.504,9.03L9.823,9.028 5.15,9.025 12.273,1.903 10.369,0 1.903,8.466 0,10.369 10.369,20.739 12.273,18.836 5.144,11.706 9.822,11.709 12.502,11.711 20.912,11.715 20.913,9.035z" 
                                    Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    <Viewbox Width="55" Height="55" Grid.Column="2">
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,4,4" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Path Data="F1M53.214,40.132C54.801,36.559 55.708,32.607 55.708,28.435 55.708,12.757 43.212,0 27.854,0 12.495,0 0,12.757 0,28.435 0,44.116 12.495,56.873 27.854,56.873 32.587,56.873 37.042,55.653 40.95,53.521" 
                                          Fill="White"/>
                            <Path Data="F1M46.556,38.537L45.676,39.265 45.723,46.108 28.875,46.108 28.875,44.318 28.221,44.594 28.221,42.656 46.556,35.641z M27.854,0C23.121,0,18.666,1.221,14.759,3.353L24.395,25.827C33.549,28.967 39.062,26.315 40.16,25.926 41.325,25.514 42.419,25.702 43.139,25.904 44.271,26.215 46.152,28.391 45.442,29.216 41.664,33.584 30.583,38.32 28.825,38.204 27.066,38.092 23.007,38.156 23.007,38.156L22.645,39.563 14.373,41.318C14.373,41.318 13.041,38.472 12.885,37.841 12.728,37.209 13.26,36.858 13.26,36.858 12.355,36.334 11.869,33.725 11.626,31.787L9.378,32.791 2.494,16.743C0.906,20.314 0,24.267 0,28.439 0,44.117 12.496,56.873 27.854,56.873 43.213,56.873 55.708,44.117 55.708,28.439 55.708,12.759 43.213,0 27.854,0" 
                                          Fill="#FFFF8241" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                                <Path.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="1" ScaleX="-1"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Path.RenderTransform>
                            </Path>
                        </Grid>
                    </Viewbox>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonMouseOverBackground}" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GrayButtonIsPressedBackground}" />
                </Trigger>


            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="SwitchButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseButtonWithArrowStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NormalButton}" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="42,0,70,0"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ArrowButton}" />
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,0"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

And now the content of the button changing according to the Content property in:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource SwitchButtonStyle}" Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```