# Setting a Button Image to Binding in its Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am finding that I am creating the same `Button` style for multiple buttons but only changing one part - the image that is used on the `Button`. An example;

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/MainWindowIcons/Staff.ico" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource HoverUnderlineStyle}" Text="Staff" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
     </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

This is the code for the staff `Button`. If I wanted to add another button I'd replicate the whole style but just change the `Source` of the `Image`.

Is there a way I can have on style and then set this on the `Button` itself - meaning that I don't have to replicate the style multiple times?

Comment: You don't also change the Text property of the TextBlock?

Comment: Try giving this way. <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Content}"

Comment: check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34182134/wpf-how-to-pass-content-property-between-styles-and-controltemplate

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Praveen with doing that Praveen, how do I set it up on the `Button` itself?

Comment: @CBreeze `<Button><Button.Content><BitmapImage UriSource=.../></Button.Content></Button>`, but how about the Text?

Comment: @Clemens Hi Clemens thanks for the answer. I would set the Text property on the button itself.

Comment: How that, when the Content is already set to a BitmapImage? That's why I initially asked if you don't want to change the Text. You might use the `Tag` property instead of `Content` for the image.

Comment: @Clemens Apologies I got confused. You're right and I shall use the Tag property for the image. Does that then mean I can use the Content for the Text of the TextBlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement two attached properties - one for the `Image` source and one for the text - that you can set on any `Button`:

```
public class ButtonProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ImageSource", typeof(Uri), typeof(ButtonProperties));

    public static Uri GetImageSource(Button button)
    {
        return (Uri)button.GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImageSource(Button button, Uri value)
    {
        button.SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Text", typeof(Uri), typeof(ButtonProperties));

    public static string GetText(Button button)
    {
        return (string)button.GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetText(Button button, string value)
    {
        button.SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Then you only need to define the `ContentTemplate` once as a resource, for example in your App.xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=(local:ButtonProperties.ImageSource), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(local:ButtonProperties.Text), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Usage:

```
<Button local:ButtonProperties.Text="Staff"
                local:ButtonProperties.ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/Resources/MainWindowIcons/Staff.ico"
                ContentTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}" />
```